# (Django) Model of particular person with this User already exists

Tags: python, django

Dear StackOverFlow community,

Basing on a built-in user User model I've created my own model class called "ModelOfParticularPerson". The structure of it looks like this:

```
class ModelOfParticularPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nickname =  models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=False)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Required')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Unfortunately, after loggin in with the usage of particular account, whenever I am trying to reedit the profile, I do get following error:
"Model of particular person with this User already exists."
Any advice is priceless.
Thanks.

ps. 
views.py:
[..]

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ModelOfParticularPerson
    form_class = ModelOfParticularPersonForm
    success_url = "/accounts/profile/"  # You should be using reverse here

    def get_object(self):
        # get_object_or_404
        return ModelOfParticularPerson.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request):
        form = ModelOfParticularPersonForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("FORM NOT VALID!")
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = self.request.user
            profile.save()
            return JsonResponse(profile)
        else:
            return render_to_response('my_account.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    [..]
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(template_name='my_account.html'), name='my_account'),
]
```

forms.py

```
class ModelOfParticularPersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelOfParticularPerson
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
                   'user':forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'uploaded_at':forms.HiddenInput(), 
                   'created':forms.HiddenInput(), 
        }
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')` since you already have `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the instance to the form, otherwise Django will try to create a new object when you save it.

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ModelOfParticularPersonForm(instance=self.get_object(), self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    ...
```

You should try to avoid overriding `get` or `post` when you're using generic class based views. You can end up losing functionality or having to duplicate code. In this case, it looks like you can remove your `post` method. In the `form_valid` method you can return a `JsonResponse`. You shouldn't have to set `form.instance.user` if you are updating an existing object.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    profile = form.save()
    return JsonResponse(profile)
```

Finally, you should leave fields like `user` and `uploaded_at` out of the model form instead of making them hidden fields.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new forum in your `post` method of view, but you're not passing existing model object to it. That leads to creation of new model, which fails, because object already exists.

Instead of overwritting `post` method, put saving of object inside `is_valid` method and use already provided form object (passed to you by method parameter).